# Extender una línea usando matplotlib en python

Tags: python, matplotlib

con el siguiente código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=plt.plot([1/2,0],[0,1])
b=plt.plot((-2,0),(0,6))
c=plt.scatter([-1],[3])
plt.ylabel('Eje y')
plt.xlabel('Eje x')
plt.title('Lineas')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Genero la siguiente gráfica:
[image: <code>genero el la siguiente gráfica:</code>]

Cómo puedo lograr que las lineas sean más largas, de modo que se note la intersección entre las 2 rectas?

Answer (score 1):

Si tan solo quieres una recta paralela a otra podrías cambiar:

```py
a=plt.plot([0,-2],[0,6])
```

Eso hará que en el eje X se ocupe desde `[0,-2]` y en el eje Y desde `[0,6]`.

Por lo que quedaría así:

[image]